# Changing child object pointer to parent pointer (without memory leak)

Tags: c++, pointers, object, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

In this question: [What do conditionals do to polymorphic objects in C++? (inclusion polymorphism)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101244/what-do-conditionals-do-to-polymorphic-objects-in-c-inclusion-polymorphism/34101333?noredirect=1#comment55954909_34101333)

I have a situation where a parent pointer is pointing at one of two possible objects determined by the preceding conditional statement. Here is the code: (Reposted with solution)

```
ClassParent *parentPointer; //Declare pointer to parent

if (condition) {
    ClassChild1* mychild = new mychild1(); //Initialize ClassChild1 object with pointer mychild
    parentPointer = mychild;//Parent pointer points to child1
}

if (!condition) {
    ClassChild2* mychild = new mychild2(); //Initialize ClassChild1 object with pointer mychild
    parentPointer = mychild;//Parent pointer points to child2  
}

cout << *parentPointer;
```

The problem is, my object is created with mychild pointer but I want this pointer to be temporary. Once the object is pointed to by the parentPointer, I want to make sure mychild pointer is deleted (just the pointer not the object).

I'm not sure if this will happen when it goes out of scope, because the pointer was declared within the context of 'new'.

Do I need to delete the mychild pointer manually? If so, how do I delete the pointer without causing the parentPointer to go out of bounds?

Comment: The variable `mychild` is just a pointer declared on the stack, it doesn't need to be freed. But why use another variable anyway? Just assign `parentPointer` directly.

Comment: Pointers are fundamental data types and don't do anything when they go out of scope. The memory for the pointer itself gets released, but the object pointed to isn't. If you call delete, you deallocate the object. If when to delete the object becomes a question, use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: What I'm concerned about is whether or not parentPointer could be assigned directly. How would you do that?

Comment: I didn't think you could do that because its polymorphic, parentPointer is type parent, mychild is type ClassChild1 or ClassChild2. I need the pointer to be a parent pointer and not a child pointer because I'm keeping bbjects of Child1 and Child2 in the same Parent array

Comment: Keeping the pointers of both objects in a parent array, I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A { };

class B: public A { };

class C: public A { };

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A &){ return os << 'A'; }

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const B &){ return os << 'B'; }

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const C &){ return os << 'C'; }

int main(){
    A *a1=new B;
    A *a2=new C;
    cout << *a1 << *a2 << '\n';
}
```

It will print `AA`, not `BC`.  Even though the pointers `a1` and `a2` really point to objects of types `B` and `C`, they're still of type “pointer to `A`”, and when you apply the `*` operator to them, the expression will have the type `A`.

To really exercise object polymorphism, you should use virtual functions.

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual char getName() const { return 'A'; }
};

class B {
    public:
        char getName() const { return 'B'; }
};

class C {
    public:
        char getName() const { return 'C'; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A &a_like){
    return os << a_like.getName();
}

// remove ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const B &)

// remove ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const C &)
```

**EDIT:** Lastly, since you mentioned not having memory leaks and also storing pointers to objects of derived types in a collection of pointers to the base type, you'll probably want to make your destructors `virtual` as well.  By doing so, the resources freed at the destruction of the pointer (through the `delete` operator) or reference to the base type will perform the necessary clean-up actions on the actual underlying object of the derived type.

Don't forget, also, that if you have something like `vector<SomeClass *>`, the pointer elements will not be individually `delete`d at the time of destruction of the vector container.  You should either explicitly `delete` each element before the vector gets destroyed, envelop your pointers with a smart pointer (such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`), or create your own RAII envelope to your polymorphic objects, perhaps aware of with move operations.

Comment: I am using victuals, except on the free helper operators, just because I'm #including the file anyways, so my one operator overload is being imported anyway, and since it takes a base case reference, it seems to work.

Comment: The interesting thing here, to me, is your A *a1= new B; I din't know you could do that. Is the syntax basically <pointer-type> *<pointer-name> new <object type> -- cause I had no idea that could be done. Could you also do A *a1 in one line, and then later do a1 = new B?

Comment: I'll have to take a look at virtual destructors, cause I'm not too familiar with those even though I have them. But I'm not sure what you mean by vector<SomeClass *> ... is this a template declaration?